# How to train and implement confidence in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am trying to train a CNN which will output  (x,y) co-ordinates for face features such as left eye start, left eye end, left eye center, right eye start, right eye center and right eye end. According to coursera course deep learning specialization I need to get a 0 and 1 value (true or false) for each points and then x and y coordinate output for each. If the value is 0 (False) I need to ignore the output of x and y during training.

I tried to search for a way to do this but failed to find. Finally I thought of setting all the absent (Data for which we don't have a particular feature) x, y co-ordinates of the data to 0 and the train the following network.

```py
def get_model():
    inputs = Input(shape=(96, 96, 1))

    # a layer instance is callable on a tensor, and returns a tensor
    x = Conv2D(16, kernel_size=5, padding='same', activation='relu')(inputs)
    x = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=5, padding='valid', activation='relu')(x)
    x = Dropout(0.25)(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=5, padding='valid', activation='relu')(x)
    x = Conv2D(128, kernel_size=5, padding='valid', activation='relu')(x)
    x = Dropout(0.25)(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Conv2D(256, kernel_size=3, padding='valid', activation='relu')(x)
    x = Dropout(0.25)(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(1, 1))(x)
    x = Flatten()(x)
    present = Dense(256)(x)
    present = PReLU()(present)
    present = Dense(15, activation="sigmoid", name="classification")(present)
    position = Dense(256)(x)
    position = PReLU()(position)
    position = BatchNormalization()(position)
    position = Dense(128)(position)
    position = PReLU()(position)
    position = BatchNormalization()(position)
    position = Dense(64)(position)
    position = PReLU()(position)
    position = Dense(30, activation="relu", name="position")(position)

    # This creates a model that includes
    # the Input layer and three Dense layers
    model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=[present, position])
    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                loss={'classification':'binary_crossentropy','position':'mse'},
                metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

Although the classification accuracy is good the position accuracy is bellow 1 percent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom loss such that the points with confidence values below a threshold are ignored from the coordinate loss computation but not the confidence loss computation:

```
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred, conf_dim=-1, conf_thresh=0, px_weight=0.5, conf_weight=0.5):
   # compute sum of squared coordinate errors
   px_err = K.sum(K.square(y_pred[:, :conf_dim] - y_true[:, :conf_dim]), axis=-1)

   # compute squared confidence errors
   conf_err = K.square(y_pred[:, conf_dim] - y_true[:, conf_dim])

   # set loss of points whose confidences are below our threshold to zero
   px_err = px_err * tf.cast(y_true[:, conf_dim] > conf_thresh, y_true.dtype)

   # calculate mean over errors
   px_err, conf_err = K.mean(px_err), K.mean(conf_err)

   # return sum of weighted pixel and confidence errors
   return px_weight * px_err + conf_weight * conf_err


# compute a small example with numpy arrays
#                   -------
#                   x, y, c
#                   -------
y_true = np.array([[1, 2, 1],
                   [3, 4, 0],  # confidence zero
                   [5, 6, 1]])

y_pred = np.array([[1, 2, 1],  # correct
                   [1, 2, 1],  # wrong (not included in pixel loss because of confidence)
                   [2, 3, 1]]) # wrong

# run through loss function
print("Loss:", K.eval(custom_loss(K.variable(y_true), K.variable(y_pred)))) 
>>> Loss: 3.1666667
```

Comment: Although I got a hint from this code. This code is not considering the binary loss which is the loss of 3rd column. Although I got the idea but still not sure how to separate that. I mean the loss will be returned for both in that case to the same output which should not happen.

Comment: I apologize, I misunderstood that you still wanted confidence loss in addition to coordinate loss. I have updated the code to include coordinate loss (removing terms where true confidence is `0`) as well as confidence loss. There are weight terms for each loss which you can set accordingly. Is this more along the lines of what you were expecting?